# Sorting XML Elements and sorting data for a set of elements with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have below sample xml data. I need to sort the elements and data at multiple levels.
1. sort has to be happend at just below the root level like `<InventoryRecord><SalesInRecord><SellOutRecord>`
2. sort has to be happend for all the elements in each `<InventoryRecord>` or `<SalesInRecord>` or `<SellOutRecord>` on fields name
3. sort has to be happend on data in `<LOCATION_ID><LOCATION_ID_DB><LOCATION_NAME>` fields in the each record set irrespective of record set type. 
   here the important thing is that, for some records `<LOCATION_ID>` element may not available. 
   in that case sort should happen on only `<LOCATION_ID_DB><LOCATION_NAME>` values.

```
<root>
<SellOutRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSO</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>1</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_ID>2-3LG-2456</LOCATION_ID>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
    <LOCATION_ID_DB>2-3LG-2456</LOCATION_ID_DB>
</SellOutRecord>
<SellOutRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSO</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>2</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ ABC</LOCATION_NAME>
    <LOCATION_ID_DB>-1</LOCATION_ID_DB>
</SellOutRecord>
<SellOutRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSO</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>WARNING</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>3</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_ID>2-3LG-2450</LOCATION_ID>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
    <LOCATION_ID_DB>-1</LOCATION_ID_DB>
</SellOutRecord>
<SellOutRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSO</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>4</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_ID>2-3LG-2456</LOCATION_ID>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
    <LOCATION_ID_DB>2-3LG-2456</LOCATION_ID_DB>
</SellOutRecord>
<SellOutRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSO</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>6</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ ABC</LOCATION_NAME>
    <LOCATION_ID_DB>-1</LOCATION_ID_DB>
</SellOutRecord>
<InventoryRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOIV</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>2</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_ID>2-3LG-2450</LOCATION_ID>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
    <LOCATION_ID_DB>-1</LOCATION_ID_DB>
</InventoryRecord>
<InventoryRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOIV</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>4</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_ID>2-3LG-2456</LOCATION_ID>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
    <LOCATION_ID_DB>2-3LG-2456</LOCATION_ID_DB>
</InventoryRecord>
<InventoryRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOIV</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>5</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ ABC</LOCATION_NAME>>
    <LOCATION_ID_DB>-1</LOCATION_ID_DB>
</InventoryRecord>
<InventoryRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOIV</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>8</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_ID>2-3LG-2456</LOCATION_ID>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
    <LOCATION_ID_DB>2-3LG-2456</LOCATION_ID_DB>
</InventoryRecord>
<SalesInRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSI</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>3</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_ID>2-3LG-2456</LOCATION_ID>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
    <LOCATION_ID_DB>2-3LG-2456</LOCATION_ID_DB>
</SalesInRecord>
<SalesInRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSI</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>WARNING</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>3</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_ID>2-3LG-2456</LOCATION_ID>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
    <LOCATION_ID_DB>2-3LG-2456</LOCATION_ID_DB>
</SalesInRecord>
<SalesInRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSI</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>4</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_ID>2-3LG-2450</LOCATION_ID>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
    <LOCATION_ID_DB>-1</LOCATION_ID_DB>
</SalesInRecord>
<SalesInRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSI</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>7</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ ABC</LOCATION_NAME>
    <LOCATION_ID_DB>-1</LOCATION_ID_DB>
</SalesInRecord>
</root>
```

the expected output would be.

```
<root>
<InventoryRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOIV</FILE_TYPE>
    <LOCATION_ID_DB>-1</LOCATION_ID_DB>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ ABC</LOCATION_NAME>
    <RECORD_NO>5</RECORD_NO>
    <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
</InventoryRecord>
<InventoryRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOIV</FILE_TYPE>
    <LOCATION_ID>2-3LG-2450</LOCATION_ID>
    <LOCATION_ID_DB>-1</LOCATION_ID_DB>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
    <RECORD_NO>2</RECORD_NO>
    <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
</InventoryRecord>
<InventoryRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOIV</FILE_TYPE>
    <LOCATION_ID>2-3LG-2456</LOCATION_ID>
    <LOCATION_ID_DB>2-3LG-2456</LOCATION_ID_DB>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
    <RECORD_NO>4</RECORD_NO>
    <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
</InventoryRecord>
<InventoryRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOIV</FILE_TYPE>
    <LOCATION_ID>2-3LG-2456</LOCATION_ID>
    <LOCATION_ID_DB>2-3LG-2456</LOCATION_ID_DB>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
    <RECORD_NO>8</RECORD_NO>
    <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
</InventoryRecord>
<SalesInRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSI</FILE_TYPE>
    <LOCATION_ID_DB>-1</LOCATION_ID_DB>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ ABC</LOCATION_NAME>
    <RECORD_NO>7</RECORD_NO>
    <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
</SalesInRecord>
<SalesInRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSI</FILE_TYPE>
    <LOCATION_ID>2-3LG-2450</LOCATION_ID>
    <LOCATION_ID_DB>-1</LOCATION_ID_DB>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
    <RECORD_NO>4</RECORD_NO>
    <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
</SalesInRecord>
<SalesInRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSI</FILE_TYPE>
    <LOCATION_ID>2-3LG-2456</LOCATION_ID>
    <LOCATION_ID_DB>2-3LG-2456</LOCATION_ID_DB>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
    <RECORD_NO>3</RECORD_NO>
    <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
</SalesInRecord>
<SalesInRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSI</FILE_TYPE>
    <LOCATION_ID>2-3LG-2456</LOCATION_ID>
    <LOCATION_ID_DB>2-3LG-2456</LOCATION_ID_DB>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
    <RECORD_NO>3</RECORD_NO>
    <RECORD_TYPE>WARNING</RECORD_TYPE>
</SalesInRecord>
<SellOutRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSO</FILE_TYPE>
    <LOCATION_ID_DB>-1</LOCATION_ID_DB>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ ABC</LOCATION_NAME>
    <RECORD_NO>2</RECORD_NO>
    <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
</SellOutRecord>
<SellOutRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSO</FILE_TYPE>
    <LOCATION_ID_DB>-1</LOCATION_ID_DB>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ ABC</LOCATION_NAME>
    <RECORD_NO>6</RECORD_NO>
    <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
</SellOutRecord>
<SellOutRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSO</FILE_TYPE>
    <LOCATION_ID>2-3LG-2450</LOCATION_ID>
    <LOCATION_ID_DB>-1</LOCATION_ID_DB>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
    <RECORD_NO>3</RECORD_NO>
    <RECORD_TYPE>WARNING</RECORD_TYPE>
</SellOutRecord>
<SellOutRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSO</FILE_TYPE>
    <LOCATION_ID>2-3LG-2456</LOCATION_ID>
    <LOCATION_ID_DB>2-3LG-2456</LOCATION_ID_DB>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
    <RECORD_NO>1</RECORD_NO>
    <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
</SellOutRecord>
<SellOutRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSO</FILE_TYPE>
    <LOCATION_ID>2-3LG-2456</LOCATION_ID>
    <LOCATION_ID_DB>2-3LG-2456</LOCATION_ID_DB>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
    <RECORD_NO>4</RECORD_NO>
    <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
</SellOutRecord>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
      <xsl:sort select="local-name()"/>
      <xsl:sort select="LOCATION_ID"/>
      <xsl:sort select="LOCATION_ID_DB"/>
      <xsl:sort select="LOCATION_NAME"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="SalesInRecord | SellOutRecord | InventoryRecord">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
      <xsl:sort select="local-name()"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

do what you want? I think it produces the output you posted for the input you posted.